# Jetty websockets synchronized message sending

Tags: java, jetty, jetty-9

I'm using Jetty 9.3 with WebSockets API (not jsr 356).

Different threads can send different text messages to the same session/endpoint and I'm trying to synchronize this so only one message is sent to the same session at the time.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
private final ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();

public void sendTextMessage(String s){  
    try {
        boolean isLock=this.lock.tryLock(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        if(isLock){
            this.session.getRemote().sendString(s);
        }else{
            System.out.println("message not send :"+ip);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {

    } catch (InterruptedException e) {

    }
    finally{
        if(this.lock.isHeldByCurrentThread())
            this.lock.unlock();
    }
}
```

After a certain amount of time some threads remain blocked. This is not very common. To give you some stats: 17554165 messages sent -> 3 threads blocked.

Am I doing something wrong? Is there a better way to implement this?

Is it possible that `this.session.getRemote().sendString(s);` is not terminated and is keeping the thread locked?

Comment: Why are you attempting to do this?  This is built into the WebSocket implementation already, the message gets queued, processed by the extensions, and written to the network when it can.  Its impossible to have 2 overlapping messages arrive with WebSocket both from a Jetty perspective, and from a WebSocket spec perspective.

Comment: In my app I have different threads that process different information, and once the process is done I send the result via websockets. Without synchronization sometimes messages are not received or are overlapped.

Comment: Not possible to have overlapped messages in websocket, the spec just doesn't support/allow it.  That would break the protocol and be rejected by both endpoints, and all intermediaries.    Not received is worrisome, but I suspect it something else you are dealing with as many high traffic websites do exactly what you are doing with Jetty websockets now, and without issue.